# ColdFusion - List Through Next Day

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Having trouble listing spots available into next day when they pass over midnight.  So if a facility opend at 7am and closes at 1am - I can't get the listing past midnight.

If things are set to open t 7am and close 11pm - all works well. It is problematic going into next day past midnight.

Starting here where I think my problem is the enddate loop.

Thoughts?

```
  <CFSET startdate = #CREATEODBCDATE(pdate)#>
  <CFSET enddate = #CREATEODBCDATE(pdate)#> 

  <cfset schdate = '#startdate#'>

  <cfif sadd.tclose lte sadd.topen>
    <cfset enddate = #DateAdd('d', 1, 'enddate')#>
  </cfif>

  <cfloop index="dtToday" from="#StartDate#" to="#EndDate#">
      <cfoutput>
        <cfset usedate="#CreateODBCDate(dttoday)#">
        <cfset stime = (DateFormat( usedate, "yyyy-mm-dd" ) & " " & "#TimeFormat(sadd.topen)#") />
        <cfset etime = #DateAdd('n', sadd.increment, '#stime#')#>
        Output Stuff
      </cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
```

Comment: Why are you using CreateODBCDate? What is the value of pdate? What is sadd.tclose and sadd.topen? More context is required.

Comment: You don't need to wrap variables in `<cfset` in `# #`, e.g. `<cfset etime = #DateAdd('n', sadd.increment, '#stime#')#>` could be written as just `<cfset etime = DateAdd('n', sadd.increment, stime)>`

Comment: {d '2015-02-25'} and {d '2015-02-25'} - Close: 1899-12-30 01:00:00.0 - Open: 1899-12-30 06:00:00.0 - but I am only using the time portion for open close - TimeFormat(sadd.topen)

Comment: That information belongs in the question. What is the result of the code above? What result did you expect instead? Side note, the line `DateAdd('d', 1, 'enddate')` will fail because "enddate" will be handled as a string of characters, not a variable, due to the quotes.

Comment: ARRRGHH - Damn quotation marks...  DateAdd('d', 1, enddate) - gets me going end populating...

Comment: From where does pdate come?